# Crawl website with asynchonous content behind a login with PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have a website in my local network. It hidden behind a login. I want my PHP code to get into this website and copy content of it. The content isn't posted right away, it is loaded only after 1-3 seconds.

I already figured out how to log in and copy website via cURL. But it shows only what was posted right away, the content that I'm aiming for is added after this 1-3 seconds.

```
<?php
$url = "http://@192.168.1.101/cgi-bin/minerStatus.cgi";

$username = 'User';
$password = 'Password';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch)){
    //If an error occured, throw an Exception.
    throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
}
echo $response;

?>
```

The output are empty tables. And I'm expecting them to be filled with data that shows up a bit later on this website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `curl` simply makes an HTTP-request and returns the response body to you. The table on the target page is probably populated [asynchronously](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) using JavaScript. You have two options here:

1. **Find out what resources are requested and use `curl` to get them directly.** For this open the page in your browser and check the [developer tools for outgoing AJAX requests](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/). Once you figured out what file is actually loaded there simply request that instead of your `$url`.
2. **Use an emulated / headless browser to execute JavaScript.** If for any reason the first option does not work for you, you could use a [headless browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser) to simulate a real user navigating the site. This allows for full JavaScript capabilities. For PHP there is the great [Symfony/Panther](https://github.com/symfony/panther) library that uses facebooks webdriver under the hood and works really well. It will be more work than the first solution so try that first.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thanks to developer tools link that you gave I found out that content that fills this table is under this 3 links:
$url = "http://@192.168.1.x/cgi-bin/miner_summary.cgi";
$url = "http://@192.168.1.x/cgi-bin/miner_pools.cgi";
$url = "http://@192.168.1.x/cgi-bin/miner_stats.cgi";

So now I have all data that i need. Now couple of hours to find out how to display this data nicely or fit into this HTML skeleton given by first link and its done :).
Thanks ones more!
And thanks for correcting my post :), this my first one.

Comment: sure. glad I could help  :)